# what is the maximum output file size ddrescue ? ( recovered size)

Tags: data-recovery

I have a corrupted 2TB vmdk file, I mount as drive now. Recovery started 4 days before, still running now.

So I really need to know much time it will take, otherwise its can be recover huge data? Any issues there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off the output from ddrescue should be viewable, and you should see the numbers steadily rise.

There are a large number of factors that will determine how long 2TB will take to process, but the ddrescue command should show a current and average rate in kB/s which can be used to calculate how long you should expect to wait.

It's been a long time since I've used ddrescue, but I recall that you should specify a mapfile.  From the manual:

```
The format for running ddrescue is:

 ddrescue [options] infile outfile [mapfile]

 infile and outfile may be files, devices or partitions. mapfile is a regular file and must be placed in an existing directory. If mapfile does not exist, ddrescue will create it.

 Always use a mapfile unless you know you won't need it. Without a mapfile, ddrescue can't resume a rescue, only reinitiate it.
```

If you used a mapfile, and you are worried for whatever reason you can safely interrupt the process, (ctl-c or kill will work) and then start the process again, carrying on from where you left off.

Comment: Yes . i understood, map-file or log-file but its take more time. am using  ddrescue-gui. First its show 1.3 days reaming, Now its going more than 3 days . am raely panic, finally Its will work or just like a nightmare. i don't no.

Comment: I would defiantly use the command line tool.  I have no experience with any gui for ddrescue, but if it states the current and average data rates like the command line utility does, then you can work out how long it will take.  If you can't do the math then provide the numbers and I or someone else can give you an estimate.